# Display a message when cursor over on UILabel

Tags: iphone, uilabel, xcode4.5

How can I display some text message when a label is tapped?
I have a label `(Address).Now` and when I tap over on it, I need to display the corresponding address in a small popup.

How can I do it?

Comment: I think there is no any `cursor` in iPhone application, right??

Comment: Interesting... How you made cursor available on iPhone (or say any touch screen device)?

Comment: How can  we enter a textfield data?By moving cursor in it .Right.In the same way for a UILabel

Comment: I mean when our hand overs it like in the case for textfield

Comment: @arizah Dear... have you tested any app in device? If so, you may know that there is no any hand or cursor in it... You probably say this because you tested device on simulator where we see cursor, but it  works as a finger touch for simulator.... :)

Answer (score 2):

I found out from your comment that you actually want to have a pop up on **tap event.**

All you need to do is

Have a button on the UILabel (on which you want to show pop up).
Make button of cutom type (It will make the button disappeared).
After that write a method to show pop up, and connect it to that custom button.

For creating a pop up, you can use UIView of desired size and position & make it appear/disappear on custom button tap event (touch up inside).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I can do like this.But I want it on hover event if there is any?

Comment: Sorry, No Hover event is there for any touch screen device.